# In react native problem with search bar when i clear input field data does not back to normal

Tags: react-native

[I'm making app in react-native and everything works well but I have problem to set filter bar properly. It works only in one direction, for example when I write something inside input, i see results which fits, however when i delete characters from input, data doesn't back to normal and i see nothing eventho filterBar is empty, does anyone has suggestions how to fix it?
here is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npWgV.png)

Comment: what? where is the code?

Comment: click on the link above